# calculating large number powers in matlab

Tags: matlab, encryption, rsa

I am trying to figure out how to compute large powers of huge numbers in matlab to do 
RSA encryption.

For example: A 50+ digit integer raised to the power of 999999.

Answer (score 3):

You can use exponentiation by squaring:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: -1: this is not an answer, just a link. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, So what? You want me to give a class about fast exponentiation, or copy/paste wikipedia? It is link toward what he is looking for.

Comment: the wiki link might change or disappear altogether. A more complete answer will persist. Moreover, it's forum rules and guidelines; don't flame me for pointing out you're not following them.

Comment: It is an answer, with an additional link. If OP wants more info on this, he can click the link or look further himself if it's broken. Fair enough to be an answer.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: If this were an answer, then every answer on SO would merely be a link to the appropriate google query. SO aims to be more than that; I will not yield :) Do I want you to give a class implementing it, or copy-paste wikipedia? Yes! That is the intention of this forum. Copy-pasting the one or two relevant sentences sure would help explain your mock implementation.

Answer (score 2):

So the end result will be around `1e49^1e6 = 1e49000000`. This is too large a number for any basic matlab datatype to hold. A solution is to use the [vpi toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725) of the file exchange; it can handle large numbers, at the cost of speed.

A better solution would exist in getting your end objective on a different manner; ie redefine the formulas to get the final result..

Answer (score 0):

We need to implement some form of large number data type
For C this is done using GMP Multiprecision library or LibToMMath Library
There are many others as well
For Matlab may be this will be helpful
[>>> LInK <<<](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446)